# Adding "make" to path

Tags: c++, build

So I am using eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) and I am compiling with Cross GCC. Every time I go to build my project though I run into the issue of it saying the program "make" is not found in PATH. I have been unable to locate how to add make properly to my path. I don't fully understand how to resolve this issue so any info you would need such as my path I can add just ask if you need it.

Just to clarify I also don't know how to find make.

Comment: What operating system and shell are you using? Normally, when you install the build tools, it puts the bin directory of the tools in your PATH, but you could do so manually. If you're using `bash` you could edit your `~/.profile` and put it there (`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/make/` for example).

Comment: Windows 10 operating system. I am having trouble figuring out my shell

Comment: If you are using the command prompt or the PowerShell, then you want to click on the start menu, type in "this pc", right click on "This PC", select "Properties", click on "Advanced System Settings", click the "Advanced" tab, click the "Environment Variables..." button. You'll get a dialog that lets you set your user Path setting. There, isn't Windows a lot easier than Linux? ;)

Comment: is their a way to find make so I can set it as the path?

Comment: You could open Windows Explorer and do a search. Or, lookup the install documentation for your development tools and it may tell you.